# How to get an generic image icon for image field type (like Generic File formatter for file field)

Tags: 8, media

I have media field on a paragraph entity.
This field can hold media types, files, image etc.

Looking at admin/structure/media/manage/file/display there is a generic file formatter. However, for image - admin/structure/media/manage/image/display there is not.

So when the data is rendered, I get generic icon for word documents, but not images.

How can I get all my media items to render as generic icons?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's too broad. Well if the image field's don't have that such feature then the only way is for you to programmatically add said feature. Have a look at [Create a custom field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0). You could also look into how Core is doing that for files. Good luck. If you get stuck when you have some code to show us, then maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this issue is being worked on at : [#2568289: Not possible to reuse field formatters between entity_reference, file, and image fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2568289)

For now I've used the following code - included in the mytheme.theme file. (view mode custom_generic_file)

```
use Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileItem;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field().
 */
  function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
    __mytheme_preprocess_field__generic_download_icons_view_mode($variables, $hook);
  }
     
/**
 * Ensure generic icon view mode for image media entities.
 *
 * Image field type doesn't have a generic file formatter.
 *
 * Called by hook_preprocess_field().
 *
 * @see Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\GenericFileFormatter::viewElements()
 * @see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2568289
 */
   function __mytheme_preprocess_field__generic_download_icons_view_mode(&$variables, $hook) {
  if (isset($variables['entity_type'])
    && ($variables['entity_type'] == 'media')
    && isset($variables['field_type'])
    && ($variables['field_type'] == 'image')
    && isset($variables['element']['#view_mode'])
    && ($variables['element']['#view_mode'] == 'custom_generic_file')) {

    foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
      /* @var Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem */
      if (isset($item['content']['#item']) && $item['content']['#item'] instanceof FileItem) {
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityReference $entityReference */
        $entityReference = $item['content']['#item']->get('entity');
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityAdapter $entityAdapter */
        $entityAdapter = $entityReference->getTarget();
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $file */
        /** @var \Drupal\file\Entity\File $file */
        $file = $entityAdapter->getValue();
        $item['content'] = [
          '#theme' => 'file_link',
          '#file' => $file,
          '#description' => NULL,
          '#cache' => [
            'tags' => $file->getCacheTags(),
          ],
        ];
        // Replace for real.
        $variables['items'][$key]['content'] = $item['content'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```